# GnuPG and dnsmasq can't resolve a DNS without /etc/resolv.conf using systemd-resolve

Tags: networking, dns, gnupg, systemd, dnsmasq

I have installed the Arch Linux distribution. Arch Linux uses `systemd` as a system service suite, so it also uses `systemd-resolved` to resolve a DNS. I use DHCP to receive DNS servers and resolve the DNS. I needed to enable the `systemd-resolved` service to automatically detect and resolve the DNS. And it works, for example, for `curl` and a simple web browser, even with an empty `/etc/resolv.conf`. The problem is that it doesn't work for `gpg` and `dnsmasq`.

1. GPG. Command `gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv *some key*`
   prints `gpg: keyserver search failed: Server indicated a failure` if there is no DNS specified in `/etc/resolv.conf`. But if I specify some DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf`, for example `nameserver 1.1.1.1`, then `gpg` would work correctly and would find the key.
2. dnsmasq. I want to make something like a DNS forwarder. I want to start a DHCP server that will provide also DNS servers.
   But is it possible to detect the DNS servers automatically, not only from `/etc/resolv.conf`? To use the DNS servers that the local machine uses? The DNS that might be also received from another DHCP server, the server from which the local machine receives an IPv4 address?

Hope that it is possible! I would be glad for any help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v249/tmpfiles.d/etc.conf.in#L16

Comment: Not all programs work "natively" with systemd-resolved. See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html

Comment: @TomYan, so, it is normal that some programs don't work with systemd-resolved, even when the web browser works fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 1st problem, put the nameserver `127.0.0.53` in your /etc/resolv.conf. Systemd-resolved does not *require* programs to be using its native API through nsswitch – it is also listening on localhost for standard DNS requests (like dnsmasq would do).

This is most commonly done by symlinking /resolv.conf to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`, that way you also get the domain suffixes from DHCP.

For the 2nd problem, tell dnsmasq to read from `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` (note that's a different file than above) using the "resolv-file" option – this file will contain the *actual* nameservers that were obtained from DHCP.

(If you want, you can symlink your /etc/resolv.conf to that file, too – GnuPG's DNS queries would then bypass systemd-resolved completely.)